# How to remove quote from a user entered string and use it in another purpose?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
google = {
'Pixel 4' : 64000,
'Pixel 3' : 54000,
'Pixel 2' : 42000,
'Pixel' : 25000
}

iPhone = {
'11' : 95000,
'X' : 80000,
'7S' : 70000,
'7' : 42000
}
print("Mobile Brand = google, iphone")
print(f"{google} \n{iPhone}")
print("Please write the name of brand as mentioned in list")
m = input("Which mobile company do you like? ")  
'''Here, if user inputs google then it will be initiated as 'google' in the memory '''
n = str(input(f"Which model of {m} you want to buy? ")) # user inputs Pixel 4
m1 = m.replace("'", "") #Here I'm trying to make 'google' as google to use it for next variable
print(f"The price of {n} :", m1[n]) 
''' Here the value should be as google['Pixel 4'] and value should print 64000 but it gives type error because m1[n] is assumed as 'google'['Pixel 4']. Is there any way to initialized 'google''s to google only? '''
print(f"The price of {n} :", m1[n])
```

If I use print(f"The price of {n} :", google[n]) then the program works fine.

This is the error...
TypeError: string indices must be an integer
Please help me!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is perfect example why you should keep data/info away from names. The proper way to do this is to have proper data structure.

```
brands = {'google':{
'Pixel 4' : 64000,
'Pixel 3' : 54000,
'Pixel 2' : 42000,
'Pixel' : 25000
},
'iphone':{
'11' : 95000,
'X' : 80000,
'7S' : 70000,
'7' : 42000
}}

brand = input(f"Which mobile company do you like: {','.join(brands.keys())}?").lower()  
model = (input(f"Which model you want to buy: {','.join(brands[brand].keys())}? "))
print(f"The price of {model} is {brands[brand][model]}")
```

output

```
Which mobile company do you like: google,iphone?google
Which model you want to buy: Pixel 4,Pixel 3,Pixel 2,Pixel? Pixel
The price of Pixel is 25000
```

Comment: It's a great solution from your side and I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the model from the chosen brand dictionary.

```
print(f"The price of {n} :", globals()[m1][n])
```

Comment: while this will work, its not the best practice to use locals/globals like that. it would be better to put the phones in a dict like `phones = {'google': google, "iPhone": iPhone}`

Comment: Yes it works, but this is not the code one would like to see. The upvotes to the answers reflect that. I strongly suggest to use the approach that @buran has presented.